# How do I add weight to a sigmoid function?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to create a function that is similar to a sigmoid function, but that adds more weight to the given number. It seems like almost every number I give to my current sigmoid function will result in a number that is `0.99`. I want more to see more diversity in the output of the sigmoid function. I want more diversity in the first decimal place.

```
public final double sigmoid(double x) {
        return 1 / (1 + (Math.pow(Math.E, (x * -1))));      
}
```

```
sigmoid(0) => 0.5
sigmoid(1) => 0.7310585786300049
sigmoid(5) => 0.9933071490757153
sigmoid(10) => 0.9990889488055994
sigmoid(36) => 0.9999999999999998
sigmoid(37) => 1.0
```

I tried in vain to add weights. The modified sigmoid has the same problem but on a different scale.

```
private static double modSigmoid(double x) {
         return 0.6940 / (0.9590 + (Math.pow(Math.E, (x * -1))));       
}
```

```
modSigmoid(0) => 0.3542623787646758
modSigmoid(1) => 0.5230316926059978
modSigmoid(5) => 0.7186214460729451
modSigmoid(10) => 0.7236362324983013
modSigmoid(36) => 0.7236704900938475
modSigmoid(37) => 0.7236704900938477
```

Comment: Try Sigmoid($x/\alpha$) where $\alpha>>1$.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
public final double sigmoid(double x) {
    return 1 / (1 + (Math.pow(Math.E, (x * -0.01))));
}
```

I used $-0.01$ as an example, but any small negative number will do. The smaller the number, the wider the range over which the sigmoid will give you values not-that-close to $1$. This works because now a number has to be $100$ times bigger for the modified sigmoid to give the same output as your original sigmoid. This means that the modified sigmoid will output values less than $0.99$ for all $x<459$.